# How do I parse an int from a string?

Tags: string, integer, ocaml

I'm trying to do this:

```
let medio a b =
    (a + b);;
let () = Printf.printf "%d + %d  = %d\n" Sys.argv.(1) Sys.argv.(2) (medio Sys.argv.(1) Sys.argv.(2))
```

**Sys.argv.(1)** has to be the arg[1] ~ in **C**

Now I want to use them like parameters for my function `medio`, but they're strings. How can I parse them into int?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the 'int_of_string' function described in the [documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VALint_of_string).

Answer (score 6):

I would start with [int_of_string](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html). Generally, OCaml standard library provides functions, that converts between types, of the following form `<output>_of_<input>`, e.g., `float_of_string`, `string_of_int`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arg` module for parsing command line arguments.

Example: `test.ml`

```
  let ri_a=ref 0 in
  let ri_b=ref 0 in

  Arg.parse [
    ("-a",Arg.Int      (function i -> ri_a:=i),"");
    ("-b",Arg.Int      (function i -> ri_b:=i),"");
    ] (function s -> ()) "ERROR";

  Printf.printf "%d %d" !ri_a !ri_b;
```

To use it

```
./test -a 2 -b 3
2 3
```